# What Magento files could be responsible for redirecting to a previous domain

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, error

I'm trying to clone a server. I have my Magento in a subfolder.
For the sake of simplicity....

www.domain1.com/store

Cloned to create...

www.domain2.com/store

My managed hosting company (Cloudways) does most of the heavy lifting, but despite following the steps below, I can't figure out why...

www.domain2.com/store
Redirects to
www.domain1.com/store

I've updated the DNS (even IPaddress/store redirects to domain1.com/store)
Made changes to the .htaccess, robots.txt, etc. I've updated the core_config_data table with the new base URLs (www.domain2.com/store). I've cleared the cache and even restarted the server.

I have also done a search for 'domain1.com/store' in all the files and in the database, and the only place I find it is in the following tables....
- catalogsearch_query
- core_email_queue
- core_session
- smtppro_email_log

Which I can't understand why those tables would affect a redirect. Can anyone confirm this?
Can anyone suggest some methods or tools to get to the bottom of this.

This is my eighth attempt over three weeks. When I ask my host for help they go ahead and just do the search and replace and I can't replicate their results. It takes them a day to respond and now they are ignoring me. Therefore it's imperative I learn how to do this myself. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Using chrome? Chrome caches redirects. It a pain. So if initially you got redirected, chrome will keep on redirecting you. Clear Chrome cache, try another browser.

Comment: I am but unfortunately I have tried other browsers, and the result is the same.

Comment: Anything in .htaccess effecting the redirect?

Comment: No, for the purpose of testing I am using .htaccesssample

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this resolved thanks to 'adiltaj' on fiverr.

The local.xml file in the app/etc had memcached information between two  tags that had to be commented out. That solved the problem.

Another user (Fabian Schmengler) also gives this as a possible solution (bullet 1) to a similar question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/37304/14896).