# Cloned site still going back to old url

Tags: url-rewrite, redirect, base-url, 301-redirect

Okay, I have two domains pointing towards the one server a '.com' and a `.cymru`.

At first the `.cymru` domain was the main domain and .com the alias for it and I want to make the `.com` the main domain. in plesk its not possible to do this without creating a new webspace.

So I removed .com as the alias and gave it its own webspace and cloned the site into its httpdocs.

At first I pointed it to the same database and then changed the base urls to .com in the **mga_core_config_data table**. It still redirects to the `.cymru domain`.

So I decided to clone the database so I could test it without messing with the `.cymru` site. It too defaults and redirects the .com to the `.cymru` site.

I followed information in the article below

[Magento Redirects to Old Website regardless of what changes are made!](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37302/magento-redirects-to-old-website-regardless-of-what-changes-are-made)

**I have cleared all caches and restarted the server.**

I tried removing the database connection and then a used new browser and got the magento welcome page, as soon as I reconnected back to the database it redirected to the `.cymru` again.

**I am at a loss, server stuff really isnt my strong point, can anyone help please?**

Thanks

Comment: Do reindexing and clear cache and check again

Comment: Remove cache and check .htaccess if there is any redirect done for the old url

Comment: How can i reindex and clear cache if it redirects to old site everytime? i would just be clearing the cache for the old site.

Comment: I have removed cache and checked the htaccess, the htaccess is the generic magento version, no url specifics in there

Comment: @Random_Guy_a is your issue solved?

Comment: Yes how do i close it?